# Obtain the JDBC connection string of a Postgres database in Ubuntu

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres database set up, and I would like to check its JDBC connection string, but I haven't found any way to obtain it using psql commands or "regular" commands.

Is there any way to obtain the JDBC string of a database from within Postgres? If not, what is the proper/standard way to obtain it?

I hope this is not a dumb question!

Comment: Well that you're already connected to Postgres sort of implies that your Java code already has that connection string.  So...what are you looking for here?

Comment: No! I did not set up the database using Java. I was following the Postgres installation instructions, and needed the connection string in order to do something useful with it.